# Why doesn't gcc assembly substract rsp?

Tags: assembly, gcc, stack, x86-64, red-zone

While exploring [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/), I noticed that gcc almost never substracts from `rsp`. For example:

```
square(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi ; [rbp-4] is not in square(int)'s stack frame
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        imul    eax, eax
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Why? Shouldn't there be `sub rsp, 4` for allocating an integer on the stack?

Comment: It's the red zone.